# python smtplib not sending email with office365 address

Tags: python, email, smtp, office365

I am using smtplib with the following code, according to the office365 docs, I am supposed to use the smtp.office365.com address for the smtp but was unable to get it working with that, I tried using the smtp.outlook.com address and was able to receive the mail through this tool 
https://www.gmass.co/smtp-test#

But using the code below was unable to get the mail working with the same configuration.

```
  def send_Mail(template,P_EMAIL, msg_header):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = 'dcm@whaii.com'
    msg['To'] = P_EMAIL
    msg['Subject'] = msg_header

    msg.attach(MIMEText(template, 'plain'))
    try:
      server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.outlook.com', 587)
      server.set_debuglevel(True)
      #server.ehlo()
      server.starttls()
      server.login('dcm@whaii.com', 'xxxx')
      text = msg.as_string()
      server.sendmail('xxxxx', P_EMAIL, template)
      print('email sent')
      server.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return True
```

This is the log from the python server

```
send: 'ehlo [172.50.5.2]\r\n'
reply: b'250-BYAPR07CA0022.outlook.office365.com Hello [167.88.61.92]\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 157286400\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-DSN\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-BINARYMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: b'250 SMTPUTF8\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'BYAPR07CA0022.outlook.office365.com Hello [167.88.61.92]\nSIZE 157286400\nPIPELINING\nDSN\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nSTARTTLS\n8BITMIME\nBINARYMIME\nCHUNKING\nSMTPUTF8'
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: b'220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: b'2.0.0 SMTP server ready'
```

and the log from the smtp test tool

```
Connected to smtp://smtp.outlook.com:587/?starttls=always
<< 220 CO2PR05CA0093.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 6 Apr 2020 09:37:47 퍍
>> EHLO [172.31.0.185]
<< 250-CO2PR05CA0093.outlook.office365.com Hello [52.88.153.215]
<< 250-SIZE 157286400
<< 250-PIPELINING
<< 250-DSN
<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<< 250-STARTTLS
<< 250-8BITMIME
<< 250-BINARYMIME
<< 250-CHUNKING
<< 250 SMTPUTF8
>> STARTTLS
<< 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
>> EHLO [172.31.0.185]
<< 250-CO2PR05CA0093.outlook.office365.com Hello [52.88.153.215]
<< 250-SIZE 157286400
<< 250-PIPELINING
<< 250-DSN
<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<< 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
<< 250-8BITMIME
<< 250-BINARYMIME
<< 250-CHUNKING
<< 250 SMTPUTF8
>> AUTH LOGIN
<< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
>> ZGNtQHdoYWlpLmNvbQ==
<< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
>> bjh4RU00dlhROFdIWjlxRQ==
<< 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
>> MAIL FROM:<dcm@whaii.com>
>> RCPT TO:<maisnamraju@gmail.com>
<< 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
<< 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
>> DATA
<< 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
>> From: dcm@whaii.com
>> Date: Mon, 06 Apr 2020 09:37:51 퍍
>> Subject: SMTP test from smtp.outlook.com
>> Message-Id: <0F3W5HOSAAU4.3W8YGW3D6FX53@WIN-AUIR3RRGP88>
>> To: maisnamraju@gmail.com
>> MIME-Version: 1.0
>> Content-Type: text/Test message
>>
>>
>> .
<< 250 2.0.0 OK <0F3W5HOSAAU4.3W8YGW3D6FX53@WIN-AUIR3RRGP88> [Hostname=DB8P189MB0636.EURP189.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]``

Pretty confused now as to what I am doing wrong now. Would appreciate some help. Thanksf
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a character encoding problem.

Try to reset your password and remove any special character.

Answer (score 0):

Don't consider the site SMTP Test like working properly with office365 smtp.

You didn't display all the logs from your python code. After server.login() you should have answer like that

> reply: '235 2.7.0 Authentication successful\r\n' reply: retcode (235);
>   Msg: 2.7.0 Authentication successful (235, '2.7.0 Authentication
>   successful')

Then after sendEmail()
Like that :

> send: 'mail FROM: size=7\r\n' reply: '250 2.1.0 Sender
>   OK\r\n' reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.0 Sender OK send: 'rcpt
>   TO:\r\n' reply: '250 2.1.5 Recipient OK\r\n' reply:
>   retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.5 Recipient OK send: 'data\r\n' reply: '354
>   Start mail input; end with .\r\n' reply: retcode (354);
>   Msg: Start mail input; end with . data: (354, 'Start mail
>   input; end with .') send: 'Message\r\n.\r\n' reply: '250
>   2.0.0 OK 
>   [Hostname=DB8P190MB0732.EURP190.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]\r\n' reply: retcode
>   (250); Msg: 2.0.0 OK
>   
>   [Hostname=DB8P190MB0732.EURP190.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] data: (250, '2.0.0
>   OK
>   
>   [Hostname=DB8P190MB0732.EURP190.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]') {}

If you cannot received the email, it's probably didn't come from the code himself, but from the location where is executed. On what kind of server do you execute the code ?